# Is there a way to create a calculated field in a pivot for a subcolumn

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

In my raw data I have 2 rows per person, one with their forecast and the other with the actuals.
One of the columns is called type, its value can be actuals or forecast.
For my pivot I’m using the name in rows, and the column called type as column, so in the pivot the column splits in two sub columns actuals and forecast.
I need to have the % variance between the forecast and the actuals, but I cannot create a calculated field as both actuals and forecast belong to the same column. Any thoughts?

I have tried everything not solution yet.

Comment: Could you please add some example data and something like current vs expected?

Comment: I can't attach anything yet but let's imagine 6 rows of data with 3 columns: resource, type, and hours.
We have 2 rows for Sandra (resource), one for for her forecast and the other one for her actuals, the word actuals and forecast are in column type.
The third column is just the hours for each forecast and actuals.
In my pivot I'm suing resources as row, type as column, and hours as values. So I want to substract, know the % variance and some other stuff between the actuals and the forecast. However, I'm not able to use calculated fields, as Forecast and Actuals are subcolumns.

Comment: The only available fields are Resource, Type, and Hours, and what I need to do, for example, is to substract the ammount of hours in forecast "type" to the actuals in "type"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.